# Running NSTimer at 0.03seconds repeating - increasing accuracy

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

```
        recordingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(recordingTimerSelector:)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:YES];
```

This needs to be very accurate. I've been experimenting with it, and it seems to skip a beat every now and again. Is there a better way to run a method every 0.03 seconds?

Comment: Dispatch timers may work better, but honestly at that type of resolution you can't expect it to be perfect. Whats your target device?

Comment: iPhone AND Mac. It's reading frame rates (30FPS = .03 seconds). Is there an efficient way to time frame rates?

Comment: Can you tell us what you're specifically doing so that we may give you a better solution (if possible)?

Comment: Well, I'm basically making a "recorder" app. It's reading some data, and at a resolution of 30FPS (1 time every .03 seconds), it's saving this data as an element to an XML file. When I press "stop," it stops the timer and I save the XML file.

Comment: Specifically:     NSXMLElement *timecode = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"timecode"];
    [timecode setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@",[DMXChannelArray objectAtIndex:0], [DMXChannelArray objectAtIndex:1], [DMXChannelArray objectAtIndex:2], [DMXChannelArray objectAtIndex:3], [DMXChannelArray objectAtIndex:4]]];
    
    [root addChild:timecode];

Comment: Keep in mind that iOS/MacOS is not a RTOS....  You can improve upon your results but the OS decides when to call (and indeed, whether or not to call) your functions based upon its scheduling demands.  If the thread gets blocked for any reason, you are going to have to wait until it resumes....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSTimer has a resolution of 50 to 100 milliseconds, or 0.05 to 0.1 seconds. You could try CADisplayLink.

```
CADisplayLink* link = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doSomething)];
        link.frameInterval = 2;//thirty times a second
        [link addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
                         forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

That would call your method thirty times a second.

---

EDIT: I searched around for CADisplayLink's resolution but couldn't find much, so I did some testing myself.

I modified some existing code that logs the frame rate using mach_absolute_time() to print the interval in milliseconds between calls to a method I had set up to be called by a CADisplayLink. I did a test on a few hundred time intervals between calls for both CADisplayLink and NSTimer. CADisplayLink had an average deviance (from the target time) of three tenths of a millisecond while NSTimer had an average deviation of half of a millisecond. That's a decent difference in accuracy considering only a few sprites were rendering to the screen. CADisplayLink was 40% more accurate.

So, my conclusion is that if you want a method to be called `60/n` (where `n` is a whole integer) times per second, CADisplayLink is vastly superior. You could try running on a different thread as well, where less is going on. That might increase the accuracy of the calls as well.

Comment: You need to link to QuartzCore and import `QuartzCore/CADisplayLink.h`.

Comment: Awesome! What's the resolution of CADisplayLink? I'm assuming that because it already works in frames that it'll be much more accurate?

Comment: WOW! Thanks for putting the extra time in for this. I'm trying to get the code to work. I added the QuartzCore framework and #import <QuartzCore/CADisplayLink.h> but it shows an error saying that it's not found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @objectiveccoder001 I'm sorry I didn't notice your comment saying you needed a Mac solution too. You could try using `CVDisplayLink`, which is essentially a Mac equivalent. It's tied to the refresh rate of the monitor similarly to how `CADisplayLink` is tied to the refresh of the iPhone's screen, which is 60 times per second. I don't think you can guarantee that it'll run 30 times a second as a result. Other options are a dispatch timer based on Grand Central Dispatch or a custom built one using `mach_wait_until` or other high-precision timing functions. :/

Comment: Awesome! Well, thanks again. I'm going to research those options. I used CADisplayLink in my iPhone app version and it's absolutely fantastic. Just got CVDisplayLink to work on my mac, but it's 60FPS. I might just create some sort of code that calls another method every other time the refresh method is called at 60fps

Comment: @objectiveccoder001 You're welcome. The only problem with CVDisplayLink is that you aren't guaranteed 60 calls per second since it's linked to the refresh rate. You could time things with `mach_absolute_time` and check if the required time has passed since the last call and control things that way. However, if the refresh rate isn't a direct multiple of 30hz, it'll be off since you can only skip whole frames. Ex. skipping every third on a 75hz monitor (like mine can be set to be) would equal 25 calls a second. You could keep a remainder, but then the accuracy would be worse than NSTimer. :(